# Xero - Contacts - API Authorization Issue

Tags: filemaker, xero-api

We have successfully been able to access everything on our developer environment in regards to the Xero API.

However, when we move to our production system, we are able to do every tasks using the API except for accessing the contacts endpoint of xero.  We just do not understand what the issue might be.

How can the API work to post bills, invoices, but cannot create or access the contacts?  Is there a setting issue?  It works find in a connecting to a dev version of the Xero File (a Paid blank file), but when it comes to the production xero File (Our actual live accounting data), we cannot access contacts.

Anyone run into any such problem?

The endpoint in question is:

https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts?summaryOnly=True
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts

Tried recreating the App, even with different users, seen access priveleges inside xero, all set to advisor, still problem seems to be persistent.

Seems uniqiue only to our accounting file.

Comment: Did you try API call in an alternative App, like Postman? Also, what are you getting back - can you post your Auth error?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to access the contacts? If you get an error 401 it means that the accounting.contacts scope has not been included in the authorization link.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."